# asp.net core Identity auto logoff since 15 minutes inactive?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 3.1 Identity and set the `ConfigureApplicationCookie`'s`ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(300);`

and in Login.cshtml.cs

```
var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true
        };

await _signInManger.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, authenticationProperties, claims.AsEnumerable());
```

but it still auto-logoff when there is 15 minutes'inactive.

and I have insert an iframe to the page and reload the iframe every 1 minutes but it still not work.

how to fix it?

I do not want it to log off while some minutes I do nothing in the Page.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the expected behavior. Since you do nothing in the page the server is not being contacted and the cookie is not being refreshed. One work around to achieve your desired result (to not deactivate when the page is open and no action is taken) is to create a controller endpoint to ping at.

```
public void RefreshCookie(){}
```

Then you will need to call this action from the a continuous running js function

```
$.ajax({url:your_url/RefreshCookie}) // I dont quite remember the syntax
```

Thats the general idea. Remember if you are just standing still on a page or if you have closed your PC does not matter for the server as long as there is no communication between them.

Comment: I think it is not work I add a iframe and refresh it every 1 minute and not work too.